# install latest version of R 3.2.1 (World-Famous Astronaut) on Linux Mint 17.1 (MATE)

Tags: linux, r, installation, cran

I just switched from Mac to Linux, so while I have a basic understanding of Linux structure, there are still some things Im trying to clear up. This is one of them.

I have tried multiple ways (referencing multiple forum posts) to install the latest version of R (3.2.1 "World-Famous Astronaut") on Linux Mint 17.1 (MATE).

I tried different sources lists, the most recent being:

```
deb http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/debian wheezy-cran3/
```

but when I call:

```
apt-cache showpkg r-base-dev
```

with each of the ones I try, I always get:

```
3.0.2-1ubuntu1
```

as the most recent one available.

Also, my sources.list only contains that above deb, so I do not think its a /etc/apt/preferences/ issue.

Has anyone been able to install 3.2.1 on Linux Mint?

Thanks in advance!

- Tom

Comment: There should not be any problem to download and install it from CRAN, in ubuntu there is not any problem.

Comment: Thanks. What command did you run? Because when I tried 'sudo apt-get install r-base r-base-dev' on my other linux machine (also Mint 17.1), I end up with r-version 3.0.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out. Thanks for all the help! I will post an answer here for anyone else trying to figure this out:

First I ran:

```
sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

to get into my sources.list. To that I added:

```
deb http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/debian wheezy-cran3/
```

and then added the key: (thanks Dirk for the suggestion):

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keys.gnupg.net --recv-key 381BA480

sudo apt-get update
```

then when I ran:

```
apt-cache showpkg r-base-dev
```

to see the available packages. The top one was:

```
Package: r-base-dev
Versions: 
3.2.1-1~wheezycran3.0(/var/lib/apt/lists/cran.rstudio.com_bin_linux_debian_wheezy-cran3_Packages)
```

so, finally I ran:

```
sudo apt-get install -f r-base=3.2.1-1~wheezycran3.0
```

which worked great!

Comment: Thanks. I followed these steps successfully. As I was upgrading an existing installation I needed some more steps: `apt-get upgrade` to get the rest of the cran packages, `apt-get autoremove` (because it told me to), `apt-get upgrade r-base-dev` (because it said it was being "held back", reason not given). Then in an R session as root, `update.packages(ask=F)` to upgrade everything that I'd installed from inside R rather than from a deb.

Answer (score 2):

Briefly:

- Did you also run `sudo apt-get update` ?
- Look at `apt-cache policy r-base-dev` which will shows which versions apt "knowns"
- Mint ain't Debian so hell may still break loose ...

Comment: Thanks for the reponse! I love your work in R! So, when I run sudo apt-get update at the very end I get "W: GPG error: http://cran.rstudio.com jessie-cran3/ Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 06F90DE5381BA480". But when I run "apt-cache policy r-base-dev" I get:

Comment: "r-base-dev:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 3.2.1-1~jessiecran3.0
  Version table:
     3.2.1-1~jessiecran3.0 0
        500 http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/debian/ jessie-cran3/ Packages
     3.0.2-1ubuntu1 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages

Comment: Can I install the "3.2.1-1~jessiecran3.0" using: "sudo apt-get install -f r-base= 3.2.1-1~jessiecran3.0" even though the public key isnt varified (from message above)?

Comment: 'W' is a warning, not an error. See the Debian + Ubuntu READMEs for how to add that key.