# ansible r-base 3.2 install on debian

Tags: r, debian, ansible

To get r-base version 3.2 on debian 8 "Jessie" I use the documentation:

https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/debian/#debian-jessie-stable and [install latest version of R 3.2.1 (World-Famous Astronaut) on Linux Mint 17.1 (MATE)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31295828/install-latest-version-of-r-3-2-1-world-famous-astronaut-on-linux-mint-17-1-m)

In short we add

```
deb http://<favourite-cran-mirror>/bin/linux/debian jessie-cran3/
```

to the file /etc/apt/sources.list and eventually sign it with:

```
apt-key adv --keyserver keys.gnupg.net --recv-key 381BA480
```

What is the correct way to do this in **ansible** ?

Comment: this is related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16093331/how-to-install-r-version-3

Comment: have you tried `apt-key` and `apt-repository` modules of `ansible`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be straightforward using `apt-key` and `apt-repository` modules as Frank suggested:

```
- name: Add the APT key for official R repository
  apt_key: id="381BA480" keyserver="pgp.mit.edu" state=present

- name: Ensure APT official R repository
  apt_repository: repo="deb http://mirror.ibcp.fr/pub/CRAN/bin/linux/{{ ansible_distribution|lower }} {{ ansible_distribution_release|lower }}-cran3/"
```

This should create the file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mirror_ibcp_fr_pub_CRAN_bin_linux_debian.list` with the following content:

```
deb http://mirror.ibcp.fr/pub/CRAN/bin/linux/debian jessie-cran3/
```

You can now use `apt` module:

```
- name: Install the R packages
  apt: name=r-base install_recommends="yes" state=present
```

Note that obviously, the `<favourite-cran-mirror>` or keyserver can be adjusted as you wish.